# Function to combine rows in a table

Tags: javascript, html

Does anyone know if such a function of plugin exists where I can pass in a table and it returns the table with cells combined where there is repeated data. So it would create something that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Where is your data coming from, would it be easier to do it in the backend?

Comment: @RaulSauco It's actually a datatable that needs to be put onto a pdf. So when I grab the html it doesn't keep the "rowsGroup" functionality. So front end would be best. Ideally something like `let newTable = tableFunction(table)`